# In SolidJS, how do Signals get repeatedly rendered into the DOM?

Tags: solid-js

I think I understand Signals, Reactions, Derivations quite well in terms of Reactivity.

However, I can't understand how all of a sudden, putting them into an `App()` function and the Signals can be updated into the DOM repeated when the Signals are updated?

I think perhaps this [doc](https://indepth.dev/posts/1289/solidjs-reactivity-to-rendering) explains it, but it seems too complicated to understand. Can it be explained in a couples of paragraphs?

For example, I'd imagine

```
<div>{value()}</div>
```

where `value()` comes from

```
const [value, setValue] = createSignal(123);
```

would have some code to have some Reaction that reacts to the Signal `value`'s change and update the DOM, but how did it happen?  Is this `createSignal()` the same as the regular `createSignal()` or is it a special edition that sets up a Reaction to update the DOM?  Also related is, since `App()` is only run once, then how come the `render()` needs to take `() => <App />` but cannot just take `<App />` as its first argument? If `App()` runs once only, that means `() => <App />` runs once only. So then why not just simply give a `<App />`?

Comment: Putting code in JSX creates an implicit reaction.

Comment: "Putting code in JSX creates an implicit reaction"... I think it is done by the "system" or build tool or the SolidJS compiler? In a way, we'd just think: it is some magic done, similar to Svelte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Components are compiled into effects that gets re-evaluated when the signal's value is updated. Let me explain it briefly:

1. When invoked `createSignal` creates a subscribers list and returns a pair of functions: a setter and a getter. Every signal keeps its own subscribers list.

The setter function sets the next value, while the getter function returns the stored value.

2. When invoked, the getter function gets the stored value but before getting the value, the effect that wraps the getter invocation will be added to the signal's subscriber list.

So, reading a value, in other words invoking the getter as `value()`, automatically inserts an effect into the signal's subscribers list.

This effect can be created via `createEffect` maunally or automatically when `JSX` component gets compiled into a function call.

So, when the signal gets updated, it is these effects that gets executed.

3. JSX components are compiled into effects, which creates and updates DOM nodes whenever signal value changes.

Lets see how components gets compiled into effects:

```js
import { createSignal } from 'solid-js';

export const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);

  return <div>{count()}</div>
};
```

The compiled output for the above component is as follows:

```js
import { createSignal } from 'solid-js';

import { template as _$template } from "solid-js/web";
import { insert as _$insert } from "solid-js/web";

const _tmpl$ = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<div></div>`, 2);

export const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
  return (() => {
    const _el$ = _tmpl$.cloneNode(true);
    _$insert(_el$, count);
    return _el$;
  })();
};
```

See the line `` _$template(`<div></div>`, 2) `` and `_tmpl$.cloneNode(true)` and `_$insert(_el$, count);`.

Here:

- `_$template` function creates a template reflecting the component's DOM structure.
- `cloneNode` clones the template.
- `$insert` function populates the values and inserts the returned DOM element into its parent DOM element.

So, it is not the getter's invocation but the re-running the whole effect that has the getter invocation updates the DOM.

> How come the render() needs to take () =>  but cannot just take  as its first argument?

The documentation answers your question. Solid's runtime keeps tracks of who owns the whom in order to prevent memory leaks. Passing a function is needed for settings things up.

> It's important that the first argument is a function: do not pass JSX directly (as in render(, ...)), because this will call App before render can set up a root to track signal dependencies within App. https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#render

So, you can see `<App />` as a function invocation, or more accurately as the invocation of the `App` function. So, you will be feeding a value to the `render` function.

If you don't like `() => <App />` syntax, you can pass `App` function like so:

```js
const dispose = render(App, document.getElementById("app"));
```

The important thing is you provide a function that returns a JSX element which will be used as the root element of your application.

Comment: looks great. Are you a developer for SolidJS? (1) So in a way, I can treat it like in SICP, some kind of magic: don't worry, the signal will be hooked up to the DOM element at a granular level so that when the signal changes, the DOM display will change accordingly. (2) Does it involve compiling like you said, so it is similar to Svelte. That is, the code as is won't do the job, but it has to be tweaked in some way (similar to how Svelte changes `count = 1;` to use a setter instead)

Comment: SICP (and Brain Harvey) mentioned it is magic when you can just take it for granted, or that's how the "black box" works -- such as why `4 * 5` gives `20`? You can just treat it as magic... or why `(cons 3 4)` can "glue" together 2 items? You can just treat it as "magic". So is Unix's system call `read()` -- why can it read something from the hard drive? You can just treat it as magic even though it is still written in C. That's like what the black box says what `read()` does and the black box can be viewed as magic